# Sampling System Line Flow Rate

Tags: pressure, gas, systems-design

I'm an application engineer for sampling system products. Currently, one of my customers wants to measure their gas sample composition and create a new sample system to achieve it. They don't have any idea on how to make sure the flow rate in the created sample line. The system will look like this.

[image: system design]

[see system design image here](https://i.ibb.co/Bttp2ry/draw-io-le-FQmsv-ZTt.png)
[image: System Design]

If we only knew the pressure (P1) at the sample source point, the pressure at the return point (P2), and flow + diameter of the source point, can we calculate how much flow rate will flow through this sample line? I was thinking about pipe junction theory (A1V1 = A2V2 + A3V3) but still couldn't figure out how to implement that theory in here.

Comment: "If we only knew the pressure (P1) at the sample source point" but you do, at least you show it on the diagram.

Comment: I would work from the necessary volume/flowrate for the analyzer and size the line accordingly. You can use a rotameter or a mass flow controller to set the flow rate to the analyzer. The line can then be sized to limit dP as necessary.

Comment: Firstly, you should determine that the pressure drop taken by the analyzer is not too big, relative to the required flow for the analyzer function, and the fact that you have only ~100mbar differential pressure to work with. Then you can roughly reckon the pressure drops in the connecting tubes, using pipe flow calculators on the internet, or a Moody chart, or look up Poiseuille's law. (if doing the latter, make sure flow is laminar). Leave plenty of margin, these calculations won't be exact for real-world use.

Comment: Thanks, Ari and Pete, I should consider the pressure drop along the sample transportation line (which is usually the most contributing to the whole system pressure drop), I don't think 100 mbar will be safe enough for this, thus I've decided to use a sample pump in this. I also will note adding a flowmeter control valve in the sample system. Once again, thank you very much!